# C++11 regex_token_iterator

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, copy

Hmm...  I thought I understood regexes, and I thought I understood iterators, but C++11's regex implementation has me puzzled...

One area I don't understand: Reading about [regex token iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_token_iterator), I came across the following sample code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <regex>
int main()
{
   std::string text = "Quick brown fox.";
   // tokenization (non-matched fragments)
   // Note that regex is matched only two times: when the third value is obtained
   // the iterator is a suffix iterator.
   std::regex ws_re("\\s+"); // whitespace
   std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), ws_re, -1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, "\n"));
   ...
}
```

I don't understand how the following output:

```
Quick
brown
fox.
```

is being created by the std::copy() function above.  I see no loop, so I am puzzled as how the iteration is occurring. Or put another way, how is more than one line of output being generated?

Comment: It copies each one to the output. The loop is inside `copy`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::copy` copies elements from an input range into an output range.  In your program, the input range is the three tokens extracted using the regular expression delimiter.  These are the three words that are printed to the output.  The output range is `ostream_iterator` which simply takes each element it is given and writes the element to an output stream.

If you step through `std::copy` using your debugger, you will see that it loops over the elements of the input range.

Comment: Ah--I didn't think to try that--I'd assumed std::copy() was a simple byte-level copy from the start iterator to the end iterator.

Thanks, James.

Comment: Nope, `std::copy` is one of the Standard Library algorithms (part of what is commonly called the _STL_), and it operates on ranges of elements, just like the rest of the algorithms.  In this case, the elements are the tokens.

Comment: byte level copy from start to end wouldn't really make any sense the way iterators work.

Comment: Perhaps clarifying my misunderstanding will benefit someone else...  I'd (incorrectly) assumed std:copy was iterating over the individual chars from text.begin() through text.end().  I was expecting either one long string ("Quick brown fox"), or just the first token ("Quick").

The facts that 1) the iterator is treating the tokens themselves as the entities to iterate over (not the individual characters) and 2) std::copy was advancing the iterator over the set were the revelations for me.